# Why do pointer behave different in some cases when passed to a function?

Tags: c

I have this code example and i can't figure out why sscanf works like intended in the example function but not in the main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void example(char *seq){
    char wert;
    while(*seq){
        sscanf(seq,"%2x",&wert);
        fprintf(stdout,"%c",wert);
        seq+=2;
    }
}

int main() {
    char temp;
    char sentence []="1B2873313648";
    char *seq=sentence;
    example(seq);
    printf("\n");
    while(*seq){
        sscanf(seq,"%2x",&temp);
        fprintf(stdout,"%c",temp);
        seq+=2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `fflush(stdin)` is almost certainly [not what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sscanf` format specifier `%x` is expecting a pointer to `unsigned int`, not a pointer to `char`, so all bets are off due to *undefined behaviour*. Please take note of the compiler warnings. On my MSVC this code causes a crash.

This corrected code works.

```
#include <stdio.h>          // missing
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void example(char *seq){
    unsigned wert;
    while(*seq){
        sscanf(seq,"%2x",&wert);
        fprintf(stdout,"%02X ",wert);
        seq+=2;
        //fflush(stdin);
    }
}

int main() {
    unsigned temp;
    char sentence []="1B2873313648";
    char *seq=sentence;
    example(seq);
    printf("\n");
    while(*seq){
        sscanf(seq,"%2x",&temp);
        fprintf(stdout,"%02X ",temp);
        seq+=2;
        //fflush(stdin);
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
1B 28 73 31 36 48
1B 28 73 31 36 48
```